# Pinescript v2. strategy.close comment cannot call

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to generate alarm text for a strategy in pine script but the strategy I am using is pine v2. belongs and does not allow it. is it possible to do this?

code example;

```
strategy.entry('target_buy', long=strategy.long, qty=target02_trade_size, comment='buy 02', when=target02_buy_entry)

strategy.close('target_buy', when=target02_buy_close)

strategy.entry('target_sell', long=strategy.short, qty=target02_trade_size, comment='sell 02', when=target02_sel_entry)

strategy.close('target_sell', comment='the problem is here', when=target02_sel_entry, when=target02_sel_close)
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to use the alert_message parameter from the strategy.entry and strategy.close functions
Documentation: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}entry](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dentry)

> alert_message (series string) An optional parameter which replaces the
> {{strategy.order.alert_message}} placeholder when it is used in the
> "Create Alert" dialog box's "Message" field.